# setImageBitmap not refreshing ImageButton

Tags: android, updates, imagebutton

I'm testing the following piece of code on Android KitKat API19.  I've taken elements of my example and shown them below.  The simple application takes an ImageButton which when clicked allows you to select an image that once selected replaces the default image on the ImageButton.
Life was simple when my application could only read Gallery photos with standard file paths, but now you can select Google+, Dropbox or File Manager images, I've had to incorporate a check for a "http" in the photo string to see if I need to use a different mechanism to display the image.

```
private Bitmap photo = null;
private ImageButton b_photo;

    b_photo.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    b_photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b_photo);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        try {
            // We need to recyle unused bitmaps
            if (photo != null) {
                photo.recycle();
            }

            if (data.getData().toString().contains("http")) {

                Uri uriPhoto = Uri.parse(data.getData());

                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        uriPhoto);

                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                stream.close();

                b_photo.setImageBitmap(photo);
            } else {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                Drawable filePhoto = pathToDrawable(selectedImagePath);

                b_photo.setImageDrawable(filePhoto);

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The latter condition "b_photo.setImageDrawable(filePhoto);" works fine; hence after selecting a local photo from the Gallery the ImageButton is updated with the photo.
The issue is with the "b_photo.setImageBitmap(photo);" code, whereby the ImageButton doesn't update.  I've tried hard coding the image so I know the image I'm selecting is ok, I'm just wondering if I'm missing something, or there is a subtle difference between "setImageDrawable" and "setImageBitmap" which requires some kind of additional screen refresh.

Comment: perhaps you just need to 'invalidate' the view so it gets redrawn?

Comment: @bazza2000 `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);` returns null.

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream) returns: android.graphics.Bitmap@433c48c8 the value of which I've tested using the same decodeStream in an onCreate method and it displays the correct image, so it appears to be something Intent/onActivityResult related